# laravel console command show comments from child command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm running 2 laravel console commands.

1 calls the other one like so:

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call( 'parse:car', [ 'oid' => $v[ '_id' ][ 'oid' ] ] );
```

Now parse:car has is fair share of comments outputted to console via $this->info. But in parent command I only get exit code 0...

Is there a way to show comments from child command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the command is executed you can get its output as a string by calling the **output()** method. It will return output of last executed command.

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call( 'parse:car', [ 'oid' => $v[ '_id' ][ 'oid' ] ] );
$output = Artisan::output();
```